# Cocos2D Help: How to synthesize a 2D array object of NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In my code I have written this but it fails to compile:

In Class1.h:

```
@interface Class1 : CCSprite
{
    NSMutableArray *leafArr[20][20];
}

@property(readwrite, assign) NSMutableArray *leafArr; 
@end
```

In Class1.m:

```
@implementation

@synthesize leafArr[20][20];
@end
```

But this fails to compile, please can you tell me how to make set and set method for a 2D array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of creating a 2D array in Obj-C, the only thing you can do is create a normal array, and then add arrays to it.

```
@interface Class1 : CCSprite
{
    NSMutableArray *leafArr;
}

@property(readwrite, assign) NSMutableArray *leafArr; 
@end
```

And you add elements with:

```
[leafArr addObject:mySecondArray];
```

Comment: Okay thanks, give me a further suggestion then. I need to display some leaves all over the screen in 5 by 10 matrix, as in 5 rows and 10 columns. So how do you suggest I do this? I would of-course make a sprite and add them to the array to keep count. But can you show me how to maintain this array?

Answer (score 1):

```
int str2Darray[9][9] = { 

    {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}, 
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
    {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}, 
    {-1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1}, 

};
```

You can define 5 x 10 matrics as above in .m file. Define flag for leaves in 1 2d array & value into another 2d array. check at the time of display according to your requirement.